Why is the net electric field due to an external charge zero inside a gaussian surface?
I understand that the net electric flux due to an external charge on a gaussian surface evaluates to zero, owing to the area vector becoming negative in certain parts and positive in others resulting in a net zero electric flux.
I am taken to understand that since the area is non zero, the electric field must be. I am not sure how this happens physically, as I can't really see the electric field vectors cancelling out completely, given that they are more or less in the same direction.
It would be great if someone could help me understand how the electric field vectors cancel out resulting in a net zero electric field and hopefully provide some intuition. Thanks in advance!


Why do you think the electric field inside a gaussian surface due to an external charge is zero? It certainly isn't zero.

So, the electric field inside the sphere for a diagram as such is not 0?

" am taken to understand that since the area is non zero, the electric field must be".This conclusion is wrong. The flux is a surface integral of the dot product of the electric field and differential area and only in the case where electric field is perpendicular to the surface at all points(and constant in magnitude, eg. an equipotential surface) is the flux $BA$. Thus flux zero does not necessarily imply the net area is zero or the net electric field is 0.

This is a standard exercise. See Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics for a proof.

The integral of a sine wave over one period is 0. Does that prove that sin(x) is 0 for all x?

The electric field due to the outside charges is not zero in the Gaussian surface, however the flux is. This is because the field lines caused by the external charges enter the Gaussian surface and exit through the other side creating a net zero flux due to outside charges. This electric field is present however it does not contribute to the flux, which is why we only consider the enclosed charges.
Also the area vector is not negative, the dot product of the electric field and the area vector is negative at some points and positive at others (where it enter and exits) causing the aforementioned cancellation.

The electric field due to an external charge of a Gaussian surface is not zero inside its volume. The total electric flux is zero, since it only depends on the charges inside the encircled volume.
First, you need to understand that the electric field has some interesting property when we talk about flux. Starting with the Coloumb field of a point particle in the origin
$$
\vec E = {kq\over r^2} \hat r
$$
If we calculate the divergent of this field, it yields
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec E = 0, \quad r\neq 0
$$
The divergent of a field is the total flux per unit of volume of a field, and it is strong connected with the Gauss theorem in vector calculus. This result tell us that the flux of the field per unit of volume in space is zero almost everywhere, except in the origin, where we can't evaluate.
Now, consider an sphere, with radius $R$ $B(R)$, around the origin. If we calculate the flux of electric field in this sphere, we get
$$
\Phi_E(B) = \oint_{B(R)} {kq\over R^2} R^2 d\Omega = 4\pi kq
$$
Since this flux doesn't depend on the radius $R$, we can take it arbitrarily small, which indicates that the divergent at the origin is not zero. In fact, to agree with Gauss theorem, it should be
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec E = 4\pi k q \delta(r).
$$
This shows the strong connection between the flux and charges. The quantity of total flux per unit of volume is proportional to the quantity of charges per unit of volume. The total flux is proportional to the total charge.
Now, consider an arbitrary surface S around the origin. Using Gauss theorem, it is possible to show that
$$
\phi_E (S) = \oint_S \vec E \cdot d\vec S = 4\pi k q
$$
No matter the shape of the surface. It makes sense, because we connected the concept of total flux with the concept of total charge, and the quantity of charge does not depend of the shape of the surface that encircles it. Everything comes as a consequence of Gauss law that I wrote using the divergence operator, and I used the Coloumb field of a point particle to motivate it.

Now, imagine that in a parallel universe, the Coloumb field of a point particle in the origin is different
$$
\vec E = {kq\over r} \hat r
$$
In this Universe, the divergence of the field in the space is
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec E = {kq\over r^2}, \quad r\neq 0
$$
i.e., it is different from zero even in regions where there is no charges. If we calculate the electric flux in a sphere as before:
$$
\Phi_E(B) = {4\pi kq R}
$$
Which now is dependent on the radius $R$, and goes to zero for small $R$. In this Universe, the electric flux is not related to charges, and Gaussian surfaces could have non zero total flux, even when there is no charges inside it.

You can understand the flux relation with charges either by the Coloumb field or by Gauss law. But you should note that this is a special property and it's a law, so it can't be proved. I hope it helps.


I am taken to understand that since the area is non zero, the electric field must be.

This is an incorrect inference.
The flux goes into the surface in some areas and out of it in others. The total flux going out equals the flux going in. This makes the integral of the flux zero without the flux having to be zero at any particular spot on the surface.
The flux through the surface is zero at points where the field is tangent to the surface. Again this does not mean that the field is 0 at these points, only that its direction is orthogonal to the surface normal vector.
The field is not expected to be zero at any point within the volume enclosed by the surface.

Actually the field lines will act as curved from both upward and downward which cancel out each other effects and hence the field is present at every point but effect as resultant cancel out.
